# How do we specify onclick action for type url in lightning:treegrid /lightning:datatable

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps, documentation

Im trying to use lightning:treegrid /lightnng:datatable using below documentation

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example

for griddata of type = url i need to specify a onclick action. How can this be achieved.

**My requirement :**

1. display the data as hyperlink in the grid using treegrid /datatables
2. onclick call the controller method and redirect to the href link

Comment: please share you code - what have you tried so far

Comment: I've used the example code provided in the documentation I want click action similar to type:action but as per documentation I don't see any such thing for type:url